# Contador de objetos

Tags: java

Estou começando a estudar sobre Java, e estava precisando de um contador de objetos, ou seja, preciso colar um texto, e nele ele tem que identificar certas variáveis nesse texto, e a partir dali contabilizar a quantidade de cada variável, depois somar as variáveis e dar o resultado. Não sei se faz diferença mas seria para usar na internet.

Por exemplo, eu colo o texto no script, e nesse texto ele identifica elementos A, B, C etc, depois ele soma os items individualmente localizados exemplo:

A + A + A + A = 4A

B + B = 2B

Comment: Se percebi bem, pretende saber a quantidade de cada elemento distinto num determinado texto?

Comment: Isso mesmo, esses elementos são nomes, ou quantidades, exemplo:

"João comprou óculos, mas os óculos, são defeituosos.
Quando os óculos, sumiram.

Elena possuiu óculos, mesmo estando sem óculos, enxergava.

A geladeira era pequena para o local, então ele tratou de comprar outra geladeira."

5 Óculos
2 Geladeira

Comment: Já tens como identificar os elementos a contabilizar? Pois percebi que pretendias contar cada elemento no texto.

Comment: Sim, apenas alguns elementos do texto serão contabilizados, os quais, ficariam já na programação, pois quando eu colasse o texto ele já identificaria.

Comment: Então, supondo que estes elementos de alguma forma estariam num lista ou vetor, só nos falta saber, para cada elementos qual a sua quantidade do texto, certo @Fernando Hugo ?

Comment: Isso mesmo :),.

Comment: Por favor esclareça o seguinte: 1) É Java ou JavaScript? Sua pergunta foi feita pra Java, mas você fala em "usar na internet" e "script", então me parece que é sobre JavaScript... 2) Qual é seu problema específico? Certamente não quer que façamos o trabalho todo pra você (caso em que a pergunta poderia ser fechada como "muito ampla"). Sua dúvida é sobre pegar a entrada do usuário? É sobre "quebrar" o texto em componentes menores (i.e. palavras)? É sobre contar as palavras, já separadas? Favor [edit] a pergunta postando o que já tem e o que está te trazendo dificuldades.

Comment: Como to iniciando, tem muita coisa que não, to pesquisando bastante, mas, 1) é assim, eu colocaria os dados numa "caixa de dialogo" a qual fica numa determinada parte do site sabe? 2)Problema especifico é que realmente não sei muito sobre java, e um pontapé inicial ajudaria, rsrs, asism sei de onde partir ^^ 3) assim, é apenas "contar e somar" os items que do texto que foi inserido, os quais já estiram, numa "lista". Como você mesmo falou separado ^^. certo foi postar ^^

Answer (score 2):

Conhecendo os termos específicos que pretendes contar num determinado texto, podes resolver da seguinte forma:

1. Criar um método que recebe como argumentos o texto que se pretende
   analisar e a lista de elementos que devem ser contados no texto. A
   ideia centra-se em:

   1.1 Dividir o texto pelos espaços contidos no mesmo (utilizando a função `split`);
   1.2 Para cada elemento resultante da divisão do texto do ponto 1.1, verificar se ele
   existe faz parte dos elementos que se pretendem contabilizar;
      1.2.1 Se existir, verificar se no `HashMap` já existe algum elemento com esta chave 
      (neste caso o o elemento do texto);
          1.2.1.1 Se já existir, incrementar o valor do elemento no mapa;
          1.2.1.2 Se não, inserir este elemento no `HashMap` com o valor inicial de 1;
   1.3 O `HashMap` ira ter, no final, a quantidade existente no texto de cada elemento.

**Nota: Recomendo a criação de um método para verificar a existência ou não de um elemento qualquer na lista de elementos pré-determinados a serem contabilizados.**

Exemplo:

```
//método fundamental (1.)    
    public void coontarElementosNumTexto(String texto, List<String> elementos)
        {
            HashMap<String,Integer> resMap = new HashMap();
            String[] elementosTexto = texto.split(" ");
            for (String var : elementosTexto )
            {
                if (existeElementoLista(var,params)){
                    if (resMap .get(var) != null){
                        resMap.put(var, resMap.get(var) + 1);
                    }
                    else{
                        resMap.put(var, 1);
                    }
                }
            }            
            System.out.println("O resultado final :\n" + resMap.toString());
        }
```

O método que referi na nota, poderá ser da seguinte forma:

```
//método para verificar se existe um elementos na lista dos elementos pré-definidos
private static boolean existe(String var, List<String> params) {
        for (String param : params){
            //Aqui eu ignoro se é maiúscula ou minúscula :)
            if (var.equalsIgnoreCase(param))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Uso:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "";
        List<String> elementosContabeis = new ArrayList<>();
        elementosContabeis.add("Stack");
        elementosContabeis.add("Overflow");
        elementosContabeis.add("Pt");

        count("Finalmente o Stack Overflow em Pt foi lançado. Parabéns a todos que tornaram isso possível, poder ter uma versão em Pt é muito fixe!", elementosContabeis);
    }
```

Resultado:

```
O resultado:

{Stack=1, Overflow=1, Pt=2}
```